# Failed to resolve module specifier "@vue/composition-api". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cdn, vue-composition-api

Nothing I try seems to be helping.

Anybody know how to use composition api in vue 2 with cdn?

```js
    Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI.default);

    const { ref, reactive } = VueCompositionAPI.default;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vue/composition-api@1.2.4"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained well in the [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api). `VueCompositionAPI` is exposed in the global `window` object when used in browser via `CDN`.

```js
const {
  ref,
  reactive
} = VueCompositionAPI


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  setup() {
    let message = ref('');
    message.value= 'Hello world!';
    
    return {
      message
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vue/composition-api@1.2.4"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
```